# Jquery hide/show weird glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

This would be easier with a jsfiddle, but as god is my witness something is wrong with jsfiddle and none of my js is working, but they work on my localhost though so yeah.

So let me explain 
i have a div called topBar.
Its hidden on dom load. I have a div called toggle_bar
When toggle_bar is clicked, jquery hides toggle_bar and shows topBar

But the problem im having is that after i click toggle_bar, topBar is shown but i move my mouse a bit and BAM! topBar is gone.
I dont know why this is happening

here is my code
Jquery

```
$("#topBar").hide();

$("#toggle_bar").live("click",function (){
   $("#toggle_bar").hide();
   $("#topBar").show();
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class='toggle_bar'>
        <a href='' id="toggle_bar" class="toggle_bar_class"></a>
    </div>
<div id="topBar" class="topBar" >
    <div class="bar_frame">
        <div class="plogo">
           Page logo bla bla bla
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
          Notifications bla bla bla
        </div>
        <div class="nav_bar_frame">
        <div class="float_left_bar"> 
        </div>
        <div class="float_right_bar">
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: For the toggle_bar:a , ive used css to setup an image as href. :D

Comment: Do you want to hide/show the `a` or the `div` that wraps it?

Comment: the div, because that removes the a too right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` on `toggle_bar` should have `#` or you should be stopping the event in the `click` handler.

Comment: Yep, it's reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks, i guess without # or e.preventDefault(); the default action takes place which on dom load hides the topBar again.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you are hiding on load rather than setting to display none in the styles?

OriginalSyn is right, you could write it like this...

```
$("#toggle_bar").live("click",function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#topBar").show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: well, i could set display: none in the css file, so on toggle i would have to select the element and edit its css properties?

Comment: .show() and .hide() do that for you. Setting in styles will also stop it flashing up on screen and then hiding once the js has loaded and fired

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend (if you're using the latest version of jQuery to use the .on() or .delegate() method in in lieu of the .live() method. I would refer you to [this article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html) which does a great job of explaining the differences.

Comment: The article Adrian Martin refers to is now here : https://elijahmanor.com/blog/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Fqp/).  You should also be using

```
.on
```

instead of

```
.live
```

It was [deprecated as of 1.7.](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to prevent the link from traveling to the URL. Here is an example of how to change your click event handler to do so.

http://jsfiddle.net/dp3T2/

```
$("#toggle_bar").live("click",function (e){
  $("#toggle_bar").hide();
  $("#topBar").show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

​